# Problem with chaining promises in Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Hello i have this function:

```
exports.SentEmailWithTemplate1 = functions.firestore.document('request/{requestId}').onCreate((snap, contex) => {

    console.log(EmailUsingTemplate1);

    //Send the email
    ses.sendTemplatedEmail(EmailUsingTemplate1, (err, data) =>  {

      if (err)
      {
        console.log('error man');
        var date = new Date();
        //Create a new Log entry
        var logErrorEntry = { ... }
        //Save in the DB the Log created
        logsRef.set(logErrorEntry)
               .then(function(docRef) { console.log("Log saved with the error."); return 0 })
               .catch(function(error) { console.error("Error adding document: ", error); });
        //End Add New Data in Firestore

      }
```

What i want to do is this,

1. Trigger at the time of creating a new entry in /request -> That is
   working fine
2. Send a email with AWS SES -> This is working as expected, no problems
3. If the email is sent with no errors, then create a entry in firestore /logs, as success -> It dont work, just the emais are sent but nothing is created in the DB.
4. If the email is not set that means errors, create an entry in firestore /logs and the property will show the details. -> its
   working fine

In the step 3 is not working, but is sent the emails to the address, but if i make an error just to see if will create an error log, it wil.
I cant understand why its not working when there is no errors, i mean when its correct. It dont create a new entry in Firestore.

I think is because im not handling the chaining right, i dont know, hope u can help me with that. Thanks alot.

Update: Btw i get this error in the console when its success: Error: function crashed out of request scope Function invocation was interrupted.

Comment: what tier are you using on firebase?

Comment: Flame 25$ month

Comment: You need to return a promise that resolves only after all the asynchronous work is complete.  You're returning 0 right now.  It looks like `sendTemplatedEmail` is asynchronous, and you're not waiting for it to complete before returning that 0.

Comment: ok, but im not sure how to do that. Can you help me with that Doug? thank.

Comment: Can you @DougStevenson help me with the code, pleassse. Thanks!.